# Where can I look up some Schubert calculus numbers?

Tags: schubert-calculus

I don't know much about Schubert calculus, but I would like to know all of the intersection numbers
$$
\#(X_{w_1} \cap X_{w_2} \cap X_{w_3})
$$
where $X_w$ indicates a Schubert variety (maybe translated) in $\mathrm{GL}_5/B$, $w_1, w_2, w_3$ are in $S_5$ and $w_1 w_2 w_3$ is the long element of $S_5$.

There are a priori too many such numbers to fit in a table (medium-sized fraction of 120^3), but maybe there are some symmetries and redundancies that cut it down?

Failing that, is there some computer code that will tell me all of these numbers?

Comment: You can read through Schubert's original text: [Kalkul der Abzahlende Geometrie](http://archive.org/details/kalklderabzh00schuuoft)

Comment: Or Fulton's book [Young Tableaux](http://www.amazon.com/Young-Tableaux-Applications-Representation-Mathematical/dp/0521567246) and this was discussed on Math.SE http://mathoverflow.net/questions/134413/schubert-calculus-as-lowbrow-as-possible

Answer (score 2):

A package to compute intersection numbers in `Macaulay2` is `Schubert2` (which has its full documentation [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.4/share/doc/Macaulay2/Schubert2/html/)). `Sage` has a similar [package](http://www.math.sciences.univ-nantes.fr/~sorger/chow/html/), and a forthcoming implementation called [`Schubert3`](http://dangtuanhiep.files.wordpress.com/2012/08/munich.pdf).

Comment: Carlo, "Computations in intersection theory" goes to what looks like a short abstract for a talk Grayson gave.  Is that what you meant to link to?

Comment: apologies, I removed that link, which was not as informative as I had hoped.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but the documentation for the Sage package [lrcalc](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/libs/sage/libs/lrcalc/lrcalc.html) suggests it can do this, and even gives an $Fl(5)$ example.